# Read each line of file into a variable

Tags: posix, read

```
$ IFS= read a b c << 'EOF'
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> EOF

$ printf '<%s> <%s> <%s>\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
<line 1> <> <>
```

I'd like each line to be read into the variables. So it'd print `<line 1> <line 2> <line 3>` in the example. And to keep it POSIX.

I've tried trailing backslashes in the file and messing with the IFS.

Comment: You are talking about reading in files, but your example does not use a file. Please elaborate by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading three lines, this means calling `read` three times:

```sh
{
    IFS= read -r a
    IFS= read -r b
    IFS= read -r c
} <<'END_INPUT'
line 1
line 2
line 3
END_INPUT

printf '<%s> <%s> <%s>\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

Generalizing this to an arbitrary number of lines:

```sh
set --
while IFS= read -r line; do
   set -- "$@" "<$line>"   # cheating here by adding on the "<...>"
done <<'END_INPUT'
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
END_INPUT

printf '%s\n' "$*"
```

`"$*"` will expand to a single quoted string consisting of all positional parameters delimited by the first character of `$IFS` (a space by default).